# How do i fix armature deformation (robot rigging)

Tags: animation, mesh, armature

i am having problem with my animation, the armature is deforming the model while it should be a straight bone. how can i fix that.

[image: The model]

Comment: for objects like that (machine, non-organic), don't use With Automatic Weight when you parent, rather use With Empty Groups, it will create as many vertex groups as you have bones but for the moment it won't assign any vertex to those groups, then assign each part of your mesh to the group it is supposed to be part of

Comment: @moonboots Okay got it thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For objects like that (machine, non-organic), don't use *With Automatic Weight* when you parent, because it will create weight gradients along the mesh and this is not what you want, instead use *With Empty Groups*, it will create as many vertex groups as you have bones but for the moment it won't assign any vertex to those groups. Then, in the *Properties panel > Object Data > Vertex Groups*, assign each part of your mesh to the group it is supposed to be part of.